# how to get type of nested class with Type.GetType(string)

Tags: c#, syntax

I can create a new class with a fully qualified name like `Namespace.OuterClass.NestedClass`.  But attempting to get the type with `Type.GetType("Namespace.OuterClass.NestedClass")` returns `null`.  Here is sample code:

```
namespace Sample
{
   public class Program
   {
      public class Animal { }
      public class Vegetable { }
      public class Mineral { }

      static public void Test()
      {
         Object o = new Sample.Program.Vegetable();
         Type t = Type.GetType("Sample.Program.Vegetable"); // returns null
         Console.ReadKey();
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         Program.Test();
      }
   }
}
```

How can I use `Type.GetType` for a nested class?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

String values for C# fully qualified names use `+` between classes.  Get the type by string with `Type.GetType("Namespace.OuterClass+NestedClass")`.

[MSDN documentation for `Type.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) gives a syntax table for various types (generic types, arguments, unmanaged pointers, etc.) including "parent class and a nested class".

Adding these lines to the question's sample code:

```
string typeName1 = typeof(Sample.Program.Vegetable).FullName;
string typeName2 = typeof(Vegetable).FullName;
```

will prove the string type name equal to `Sample.Program+Vegetable`

[ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) Partition IV's associated CLILibrary.xml provides the definitive details for this convention.  The `Type.GetType(string)` syntax table in ECMA-335 is identical to that used in the MSDN documentation.